# how to get Tax/VAT number Using customer id

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

I want Tax/VAT number in my custom form field. how to get this number in my custom module and if i m change this number than how to save Tax/VAT number please give me suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this you can get  Tax/VAT number

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$vatNumber = $customer->getData('taxvat');
```

Save Tax/VAT number like this

```
$vatId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$vatId->setTaxvat($data["vat_tin_no"]); //vat_tin_no" is form field name
```